# Automated Process to Add New Data to Table

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I am working on a website which utilizes a table for presenting old and newly passed laws. As such it requires that we have a large volume of data in the tables, and we constantly have to add more data to the tables.

I know already how to construct the table through CSS and HTML; however, due to the sheer volume of data which we are dealing with, I would like to know if there is a way to create a separate admin page where we can just plug in the law information and have it automatically added to the table rather than having to physically code in all of the information through HTML.

I also have a second question: I would like to add some tabs at the top of the table which allows users to sort laws based on the year they were passed. An example of this can be seen at this site: CT Legislation | 2014 | General Assembly | Passed | LegiScan . It has several tabs at the top which allow users to sort legislation- my question is what coding language is required to add this to a table?

Comment: try looking at some of the free content management systems out there. like wordpress or joomla. those can help manage your content, but you will need someone to do up the theme or template though.

Answer (score 0):

A CMS may or may not do it for you. What really would be good is to use [Parse](http://parse.com) to hold all your data. Take a look at Data Storage and Cloud Code. You can add new laws whenever you want, and you would configure Parse to dynamically add the data to your table for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of languages for this type of solution. If it were all web based it would likely utilize php for building a password protected page (admin) page. It would also be used along with SQL to send/receive data from the Database, the it could use CSS/html for the table and content styling.

For the database you could use MYSQL (a type of database).

If this is beyond what you are comfortable with, a content management system (CMS) would be a great option. They set up the entire backend for the user and have an interface that will allow someone who knows zero code or html/CSS to put a pretty decent website together.

The great part about using wordpress is it lends itself well to someone looking to learn more about development. You can see how things can be set up with code to achieve certain outcomes and can learn more and more as you work with the system on increasingly deeper levels.

Another option is using google drive. There are tabs, a table and it is cloud based so you can share it with people you want to have access to it. Anyone you choose can add/delete and it keeps very good track of what is changed and who made the changes. It is really easy to go back an fix things if they have been messed up.